# Describing a spatial arrangement of columns

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose I have a bunch of identical matches. Their arrangement in space is subject to a single condition: Every matches touches at least another one, and touching matches must touch along their entire length and be aligned (i.e not in reverse orientation).

For instance, the two arrangements on the left below are okay (imagine the columns are touching), but not the right one.
[image]

How do I call such an arrangement?

**Edit.** I used matches for a familiar example of a (near) geometrical cylinder. I am looking to arrange true cylinders in this manner, not literal matches.

Comment: What is wrong with aligned? Besides matches don't really touch each other along their entire length, only their extremities because their tip is larger than the rest of them.

Comment: @MorganFR 'aligned' is also my first option for now, but I'd like to see whether there's some (arcane) word that emphasizes the arrangement need not be along a straight line. Matches were chosen because they're a familiar object with a similar shape to a geometrical cylinder.

Comment: looks like a discrete uniform distribution

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I don't see how this is related at all. A uniform distribution on a finite set has nothing to do with orientation in space.

Comment: Must they touch or is that only an option?

Comment: What about side-by-side (pattern/arrangement) or abreast?

Comment: @bib I editted the question so that the must touch.

Comment: Side-by-side/abreast - close together and facing the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call them *contiguously parallel*

> [Contiguous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contiguous): Sharing a common border; touching
>
> [Parallel](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/parallel): (Of lines, planes, or surfaces) side by side and having the same distance continuously between them

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 0):

You could call it an **array**

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/array

```
4. Mathematics
  a. A rectangular arrangement of quantities in rows and columns, as in a matrix.
```

Comment: The problem is I don't want the arrangement to necessarily be rectangular. It could be of any possible shape - along a curve, along a circular base (including the interior) etc.

Comment: Not an array, then. But if you felt like being poetic, you could say they were 'in array'.

Answer (score 0):

A ruled surface with parallel rulings is usually called a **scroll** in mathematics. (There are also scrolls that are not parallel ruled, but they tend to be compounded with other jargon.) Basically, you have a lower curve and an upper curve. Each is planar, and the ruling lines (cylinder axes) run between them. In your case the upper and lower curves are congruent and stacked, and the rulings run between congruent points on the two curves.